# What software do you use to manage your visual assets? (icons, illustrations, photos...)

Tags: svg, software-recommendation, asset-management, collaboration

I have thousands of illustrations, icons and photos that I usually reuse to create new visual assets (especially for illustrations).

Do you have any recommandation for a software that would help me manage, browse and find my visual assets?

It would be awesome if I could share those assets easily with my team (so my coworkers would find assets they need in one place, without asking for my help)

And even better if other designers in my company could add their own assets as well.

I am going to try Linto, but would like to know how you guys deal with this problem.

Thank you :)

Comment: This _might_ be off topic, but we'll see how it is received.  I know that in our [guidelines](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) it mentions avoiding “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?” and “What’s your favorite ______?” type questions.

Answer (score 1):

My team in particular uses Google Drive. We create folders for different projects/efforts and the share the folder amongst the team. All the folder (and all of its files) is stored in the cloud available to all members at all times even via the Google Drive app.

This only really solves half of the problem though (asset availability and collaboration). I'm not familiar with any dedicated image/icon management software for automating and assisting with organizing many design files at once though.

Comment: We use Google Drive too and I have to say I wouldn't recommend it to anyone. Ever. We moved from using dropbox (it's something like 1/4 of the price for the space we use) and I thoroughly regret it.

Comment: @Cai It definitely has its flaws but it's better than nothing at all. We also heavily lean on Drive's other integrated apps like Sheets, etc. so it made sense at the time.

Comment: Of course, we'd be completely lost without it but it does have issues (that you wouldn't expect from Google) that I've wasted many an hour on and Dropbox was painless by comparison. Just sharing my experience :)

Comment: @Cai Definitely worth looking into, thanks for the recommendation!

Answer (score 0):

My design tool of preference is Sketch App.
I use a Sketch plugin by invision called 'Craft' and it has a built in cloud library that you can use to manage and share your assets.

[More information can be found here.](https://support.invisionapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/208434046-Craft-Introduction-to-the-Library-plugin)
It is however all for mac.